# passing input type date from component to apiSlice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, rtk-query

Aloha,
i have question how would one pass the date data from user's input from component to another folder where apiSlice is located ?

currently i have filter just for today's date, but would like to change it based on users input

any Ideas?

```
FILTER JUST FOR TODAY-
var today = new Date();
var dateToday =
  today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate();

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "xxx",
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      headers.set("Xxxx", process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_KEY);
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getNext50: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/xxx",
        params: { next: "50" },
      }),
    }),
    getTodaysFixtures: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/xxxx",
I WANT PASS USER's INPUT HERE -
        params: { date: dateToday },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

ok you should read this [document](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries).

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "xxx",
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      headers.set("Xxxx", process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_KEY);
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getNext50: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/xxx",
        params: { next: "50" },
      }),
    }),
    getTodaysFixtures: builder.query({
      query: ({dateToday}) => ({      // ===> catch it here
        url: "/xxxx",
        params: { date: dateToday },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetTodaysFixturesQuery } = apiSlice;
```

inside of your component you can do this

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
const { data, refetch }  = useGetTodaysFixturesQuery({ dateToday:date }, { skip: !date }); // pass it here
```

and if you do not have any value for date input you can skip the request.
and you can also use `refetch` function and pass new data like `re-fetch({dateToday: AnyOtherDate })` for refetching

Comment: thanks for the help , much appricited !

Comment: @erik-oberta NP. Good Luck